# Running a program again on button click?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, reload

So what I need the program to do is to regenerate a new random number (**Zahl**) when the *dialogResult* is 0 (the yes option). I thought that restarting the program would be a way to achieve this. I tried to close the JFrame with *System.exit(0)*, setting the visibility to true afterwards (*f.setVisible(true)*). That didn't work, the frame didn't reappear. I've also tried *SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(f);*, *f.revalidate();* and *f.repaint()*, none of it worked.

Is there any other way to "reload" the JFrame, or would it be better to just generate a new random number?

Thanks in advance!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Random;
    
    public class Zahlenraten{
        static int i = 0;
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            JFrame f = new JFrame("Zahlenraten");
            f.setSize(500,500);
            //f.setLayout(null);
            
            JTextField t = new JTextField("");
            t.setBounds(95,10,150,30);
            f.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {
             
                public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
                    t.requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            });
            
            
            JButton e = new JButton("Exit");
            e.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            e.setBounds(300, 100, 100, 30);
            
            JLabel txt = new JLabel("Zahl eingeben:");
            txt.setBounds(10,10,150,30);
            
            Random r = new Random();
            int Zahl = r.nextInt(100-0+1);
            
            
            
            JButton b = new JButton("Prüfen");
            f.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(b);//Enter Key = button b
            b.addActionListener(evt -> { //statt evt könnte man natürlich auch actionPerformed... nehmen.
                 i++;
                 
                 String str = t.getText();
                 int wert = Integer.parseInt(str);
                 t.setText("");
                 
                 if(wert > Zahl) {
                     System.out.println("Der gesuchte Wert ist kleiner.");
                 }
                 if(wert < Zahl) {
                     System.out.println("Der gesuchte Wert ist größer.");
                 }
                 if(wert == Zahl) {
                     System.out.println("Der gesuchte Wert wurde gefunden! Du hast "+i+" Versuche gebraucht.");
                     int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Wollen Sie noch eine Runde spielen?","Frage",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                     if(dialogResult==0) {
                         
                     }else {
                         System.exit(0);
                     }
                 }
            });
            b.setBounds(10,100,100,30);
            
            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            p.setLayout(null);
            p.add(b);
            p.add(e);
            p.add(t);
            p.add(txt);
            f.add(p);
            f.setVisible(true);

            
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you could provide us with the complete code we can replicate it and then it will be easier to test the code

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the code wasn't complete. I updated it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, your approach is like shutting off a car engine whenever you want to reverse direction -- this approach is obviously unnecessary because you can change gears without restarting the car.

You need to separate the logic and UI into two separate classes. Think of your UI as a remote control, and the class containing the logic as an engine that carries out commands received from the UI. Your UI class creates an instance of your engine class.

The engine class runs a game loop that continues to run until you tell it to stop, so in programming terms, your program has *state*: a game is in progress, or the game is not in progress.

```
boolean imGange = true;
boolean ratenFalsch = true;

while(imGange)
{
    // generate random number
    
    while(ratenFalsch)
    {
        // ask for a guess
        // if the guess is correct
            // print message: right
            ratenFalsch = false;
        // if the guess is incorrect
            // print message: wrong
    }
    // ask user to play again
    // if no
        imGange = false; // game will end, but the program will still be running
}
```

Make sure your engine runs properly and you can play a game via console before you build a UI. When the game runs correctly you have to map buttons from your UI to methods from the engine. For example, your UI has a button "Neu Spiel" which calls a corresponding method from the engine, for example, `mainLoop()` where all of the logic that I outlined above is contained in method called `mainLoop`.

Organizing your code this way means that as long as your UI is running, your engine is running. Using a main loop means you can start a new game any time, without needing to stop and start the UI, and you'll get a new random number each game.

Comment: You have been very helpful, thanks a lot! You did not only solve my problem but explained to me how I can organize a games structure with simple these simple outlines. I can use this to create similar programs in the future. Thank you for your detailed response.

Comment: I'm glad you recognized that this pattern can be extended to just about any other situation where you have a UI. Freundliche Gruesse!

Comment: @aren pi:  The general pattern MarsAtomic used is called the [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.